# Javascript: Replace nth occurrence of substring in multiline string

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to replace nth occurrence when the string has multiple lines using Javascript, I tried various methods from previous answers but none of them are working when there are line breaks in a string

For example:

```
var someString="I have a cat, my cat is intelligent,\n my cat is very active";
someString= someString.replace(RegExp("^(?:.*?my cat){2}"), function(x){return x.replace(RegExp("my cat$"), 'our cat abc')});
console.log(someString);
```

I am expecting my output to be:

```
I have a cat, my cat is intelligent,
 our cat abc is very active
```

Instead it is printing the same string:

```
I have a cat, my cat is intelligent,
 my cat is very active
```

Is there a way to replace nth occurrence in multiline strings like above using Javascript

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) *"I tried various methods from previous answers"* Please show us those attempts so we can help you understand why they didn't work. *"none of them are working when there are line breaks in a string"* Did you make sure to use the [`m` (multiline) flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/multiline) on any regular expression you were using?

Comment: This question is not duplicate because it already showed the method of finding nth occurrence in single line string. It asked about the multiline behavior of the `.` so I believe this shouldn't be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You regex doesn't match properly. `.` will not match newline characters so what I'll do is `(?:.|\n)` instead.

```js
var someString="I have a cat, my cat is intelligent,\n my cat is very active";
someString= someString.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:.|\n)*?my cat){2}"), function(x){return x.replace(RegExp("my cat$"), 'our cat abc')});
console.log(someString);
```

Or use the "s" (single line) modifier

```js
var someString="I have a cat, my cat is intelligent,\n my cat is very active";
someString= someString.replace(new RegExp("(?:.*?my cat){2}", "s"), function(x){return x.replace(RegExp("my cat$"), 'our cat abc')});
console.log(someString);
```